# Can Guava Lists.transform or Iterables.transform take a Converter?

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

Usually Guava `Lists.transform` looks like this:

```
Lists.transform(new ArrayList<String>("1", "2", "3"),
    new Function<String, Integer>() {
      @Override
      Integer apply(String str) {
        return Integer.valueOf(str);
      }
    });
```

A `Converter<A, B>` defines `doForward` and `doBackward` methods that go from `A` to `B` and `B` to `A` respectively. Logically it is a pair of `Function`. It doesn't look like there's any easy way to

- Go from a `Converter` to the pair of `Function` that describe it, or
- Input a `Converter` and say a direction into the `Lists` method.

Are these incompatible or is there a way besides manually writing glue code?

The manual glue code would look something like

```
final Converter<A, B> myConverter = /*...*/;
Lists.transform(myList, new Function<A, B>() {
  @Override
  B apply(A a) {
    return myConverter.doForward(a);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava's `Converter` implements `Function`. So just do

```
Lists.transform(myList, myConverter)
```

or

```
Lists.transform(myList, myConverter.reverse())
```